# Is there a way to read data from a text file and translate it into a drl file?

Tags: java, drools

This is my text file.

```
Success
product
If the price of the product is greater than 100 and quantity less than 2 and category is "grocery" 
Then display the discount is 100
```

I read the lines and assigned them to variables but how can we change it to drl file.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*; 
public class Read {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File file=new File("demo.txt");
    Scanner s=new Scanner(file);
    while(s.hasNextLine()) { 
     String rule = s.nextLine();
     String object = s.nextLine();
     String condition=s.nextLine();
     String consequence=s.nextLine();
     Product p=new Product();
     p.setRule(rule);
     p.setObject(object);
     p.setCondition(condition);
     p.setConsequence(consequence);
     s.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Seriously: please print out your question. Show it to another person. Watch their face. Then take a watch clock and measure how many minutes of talking you will need until the other person says: "Now I understand your question".

Comment: In which file you defined the rules?Share your code and rules.So its better to understand

Comment: @Vaibs The rule is in front of you. I have to read the value and change it into a drl file.

Comment: import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Read
{
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
 {
 File file=new File("demo.txt");
 Scanner s=new Scanner(file);
 while(s.hasNextLine())
 {
  String rule = s.nextLine();
     String object=s.nextLine();
     String condition=s.nextLine();
     String consequence=s.nextLine();
     Product p=new Product();
     p.setRule(rule);
     p.setObject(object);
     p.setCondition(condition);
     p.setConsequence(consequence);
     s.close();
     
 }
 }
}

Comment: @AbhinavBhushanJha Making snide remarks ("The rule is in front of your") when your question is a scrambled mess as it was before I edited it will not endear other SO users to you.

Answer (score 0):

No, not the way you are going about it.

You might look into Domain Specific Language (DSL) and how it can be used in Drools.

But if it is just one or ten such rules you'll be better off just writing them in DRL.

```
rule product
when
  Product( price > 100, quantity < 2, category == "grocery" )
then
  System.out.println( "the discount is 100" );
end
```

(Note: The Java program doesn't make much sense.)

Comment: Sorry,  had no intention in doing so. So are dsl and dslr files a way of creating drl files dynamically?

Comment: Yes, one of the three mentioned in the Drools documentation.